# does "a halfly laced up shoe" sound English enough?

Tags: word-usage

Can't find it in google, but there must be something English speakers use to describe a shoe one started to lace up and left unfinished?

Comment: ***halfly*** has not been a valid English word for many centuries.

Answer (score 3):

Just *half* is sufficient.

A half-eaten apple.

You left it half finished.

Comment: thus "a half-laced up shoe" is correct?

Comment: I'd say the state of being "laced up" is a binary one - the shoes are either laced up or they aren't. It's just like you can't be ***half pregnant***.

Comment: >"laced up" is a binary one 
would saying "half done shoe" be better?

Comment: If a shoe has laces threaded through the bottom eyelets but not the top ones, what is it if not half-laced-up?

Comment: @yummi.yummi - if you insist on hyphenation, half-laced-up.